# Logical Addresses & Page numbers

Tags: memory, memory-management, operating-system

I just started learning Memory Management and have an idea of page,frames,virtual memory and so on but I'm not understanding the procedure from changing logical addresses to their corresponding page numbers,

Here is the scenario-
Page Size = 100 words /8000 bits?

Process generates this logical address: 
10    11    104    170    73    309    185    245    246    434    458    364

Process takes up two page frames,and that none of its are resident (in page frames) when the process begins execution.

Determine the page number corresponding to each logical address and fill them into a table with one row and 12 columns.

I know the answer is :
0     0      1     1      0     3     1     2        2      4      4       3

But can someone explain how this is done? Is there a equation or something? I remember seeing something with a table and changing things to binary and putting them in the page table like 00100 in Page 1 but I am not really sure. Graphical representations of how this works would be more than appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Isn't this just `logical address / 100` where `/` means "integer division"? If you make sure every logical address has at least 3 digits, and then just remove the last 2, you should see the pattern: `010 011 104 170 073 309 185 245 246 434 458 364` --> `0xx 0xx 1xx 1xx 0xx 3xx 1xx 2xx 2xx 4xx 4xx 3xx` --> `0 0 1 1 0 3 1 2 2 4 4 3`. You stated that each page was 100 words.

Comment: Thank you very much, did not know it was that simple.Couple of questions,after placing 0 as place holders and doing the division there would be decimals,why is it that we drop the 2 numbers behind the points and lastly how is the word size of 100 relevant and make the answer change from 0xx ->0 and 1xx -> 1? Pretty sure it's simple just need to fully understand

Comment: FWIW, normally we use hex (or binary) value to represent addresses. Page sizes are always in powers of 2.